# R cannot input quotation mark using Rcpp

Tags: r

Double quotation marks cannot be recognized by Rcpp, which shows an error of "unexpected symbol".

The following is example codes.

```
cppFunction("NumericVector attrs() { 
NumericVector out = NumericVector::create(1,2,3); 
out.names() = CharacterVector::create("xa","xb","xc"); 
return out; 
}")
```

The quotation marks in "xa", "xb", and "xc" are the problem. The codes have been written using Microsoft Word and Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the quotation marks out:

```r
cppFunction("NumericVector attrs() { 
NumericVector out = NumericVector::create(1,2,3); 
out.names() = CharacterVector::create(\"xa\",\"xb\",\"xc\"); 
return out; 
}")
```

To generalize, you cannot include a quotation mark inside a string in R without escaping. You can however use single quotation marks inside a double quotation marks string or vice versa:

```r
s1 <- "the 'cat' on the roof"
s2 <- 'the "cat" on the roof'
```

The latter approach might be in fact an easier solution to your issue with `cppFunction`, but I'll keep my original answer here because it addressed the issue itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this use of \ before " a norm, so that I have to do this every time? In the literature, only double quotation marks are used. Appreciate your clarification.

Comment: Updated the answer with this clarification.